# Parse error on input `=' 

Tags: haskell

```
initials :: String -> String -> String
initials firstname lastname = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."
    where (f:_) = firstname
          (l:_) = lastname
```

For this code. I got error

```
parse error on input `='
```

Why?

Comment: I didn't... http://codepad.org/LVecpglP
The only error I think was the last line was not properly indented. After you corrected it... the parse error should go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a tab character before the `where` keyword. To GHC it looks like this:

```
␉       where␠(f:_)␠=␠firstname
␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠(l:_)␠=␠lastname
```

So, GHC thinks that the first line in the `where` block starts at column 14 (tab counts for 8 columns iirc) while the second line starts at column 9, which causes the error.

You should use a **good** text editor that converts tabs into 4 spaces for you.

Comment: thanks. solved. Yes you are right. god damn tab

Answer (score 4):

By the way, you don't need the helper functions, you can directly pattern match on the arguments

```
initials :: String -> String -> String
initials (f:_) (l:_) = [f,'.',' ',l,'.']
```